# CallKit extension begin request

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios-app-extension, callkit

I'm developing an app with database of blocked numbers.
In my `beginRequest` method I'm doing asynchronous connection to my online database and calling `context.completeRequest()` in completion block. When is this method called? Apple documentation is not clear for me - Can It be called multiple times? The main reason is to keep list of the blocked numbers in device up to date with my database.

So the questions:

1. Are asynchronous requests available in CallKit Directory handler?
2. Is `beginRequest` method called more than once?
3. How can I create extension like popup outside my application that would make reporting spam possible without entering my application? like [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/zdvihn%C3%BA%C5%A5-to-stop-nevy%C5%BEiadan%C3%BDm-hovorom/id1187824481?mt=8) on the third screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit):

> Because this method is called only when the system launches the app extension and not for each individual call, you must specify call identification information all at once; you cannot, for example, make a request to a web service to find information about an incoming call.

You can use an asynchronous method in `beginRequest` to retrieve your data.  Once the asynchronous fetch is complete you can then call `addBlockingEntry` with each number before finally calling `completeRequest`.

I suspect that the screen you referred to in the linked app is a share extension that was invoked from the "Share Contact" button of the contact.

When you have updated blocking data you can refresh your blocking data by calling [`CXCallDirectory.sharedInstance.reloadExtension`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit/cxcalldirectorymanager/1649012-reloadextension) from your main app; you could do this in response to a silent push, when requested by the user or use background fetch.